# adding Facebook Single Sign-On (SSO) to Android AIR App

Tags: android, facebook, apache-flex, actionscript, single-sign-on

In short, I am looking to find this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso 
but for Flex apps built in Flash Builder with the facebook-actionscript-api, specifically the facebookMobile library.

I'm building a simple Android app that will display the User's friends in a list. I do not want the user to be prompted to input their Username and Password, I rather it use the device's Facebook app to authenticate (Single-Sign On).

So far I have managed to obtain the Android Key Hash from my .p12 file using keytool and added it to the app on the facebook developer site (to enable SSO).

Thanks in advanced!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Best I found was this (not free) package:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/goviral-ane-android.html

Trying it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a free sso native extension for air for android @ http://afterisk.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/first-free-facebook-single-sign-on-sso-adobe-air-native-extension-for-android